# BGP (RIB-Failure - Higher admin distance)

Tags: network, bgp, gns3

I tried to make BGP routing on this topology .. After that I added 200.200.10.0 network and 200.200.20.0 network in R1, I had rib-failure (higher admin distance) on R2 and R3 .. but I was able to ping from client at R2 to 200.200.20.1 and client at R3 to 200.200.10.1. I tried deleting the network on bgp router 3000 on R1, the ribs-failure was disappear but, I could not do to ping public ip as before.

[image: Network Topology]

R1: Show run

```
router bgp 3000
 bgp router-id 1.1.1.1
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 200.200.10.0
 network 200.200.20.0
 neighbor 200.200.10.2 remote-as 3001
 neighbor 200.200.20.2 remote-as 3002
```

R1: show ip bgp

```
BGP table version is 6, local router ID is 1.1.1.1
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, f RT-Filter,
              x best-external, a additional-path, c RIB-compressed,
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
RPKI validation codes: V valid, I invalid, N Not found

     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  192.168.27.0/26  200.200.10.2             0             0 3001 i
 *>  192.168.27.64/26 200.200.20.2             0             0 3002 i
 *>  192.168.27.128/29
                       200.200.10.2             0             0 3001 i
 *>  200.200.10.0     0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  200.200.20.0     0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
```

R2: Show run

```
router bgp 3001
 bgp router-id 2.2.2.2
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.27.0 mask 255.255.255.192
 network 192.168.27.128 mask 255.255.255.248
 neighbor 200.200.10.1 remote-as 3000
```

R2: show ip bgp and show ip bgp rib-failure

```
BGP table version is 6, local router ID is 2.2.2.2
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, f RT-Filter,
              x best-external, a additional-path, c RIB-compressed,
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
RPKI validation codes: V valid, I invalid, N Not found

     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  192.168.27.0/26  0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  192.168.27.64/26 200.200.10.1                           0 3000 3002 i
 *>  192.168.27.128/29
                       0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 r>  200.200.10.0     200.200.10.1             0             0 3000 i
 *>  200.200.20.0     200.200.10.1             0             0 3000 i
RouterHQ#show ip bgp rib-failure
  Network            Next Hop                      RIB-failure   RIB-NH Matches
200.200.10.0       200.200.10.1        Higher admin distance              n/a
```

R3: show run

```
router bgp 3002
 bgp router-id 3.3.3.3
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.27.64 mask 255.255.255.192
 neighbor 200.200.20.1 remote-as 3000
```

R3: show ip bgp and show ip bgp rib-failure

```
BGP table version is 6, local router ID is 3.3.3.3
Status codes: s suppressed, d damped, h history, * valid, > best, i - internal,
              r RIB-failure, S Stale, m multipath, b backup-path, f RT-Filter,
              x best-external, a additional-path, c RIB-compressed,
Origin codes: i - IGP, e - EGP, ? - incomplete
RPKI validation codes: V valid, I invalid, N Not found

     Network          Next Hop            Metric LocPrf Weight Path
 *>  192.168.27.0/26  200.200.20.1                           0 3000 3001 i
 *>  192.168.27.64/26 0.0.0.0                  0         32768 i
 *>  192.168.27.128/29
                       200.200.20.1                           0 3000 3001 i
 *>  200.200.10.0     200.200.20.1             0             0 3000 i
 r>  200.200.20.0     200.200.20.1             0             0 3000 i
RouterBranch#show ip bgp rib-failure
  Network            Next Hop                      RIB-failure   RIB-NH Matches
200.200.20.0       200.200.20.1        Higher admin distance              n/a
```

Comment: The AD for a directly connected network is `0`, but for eBGP it is `20`, and for iBGP it is `200`, both of which are higher than `0`, so that is a correct outcome of receiving the routes through BGP (really any other routing protocols or even statically configured).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rib-failure` is telling you the learned BGP route isn't best because there is another route -- in this case, directly connected routes -- with a better Admin Distance (AD).  On R1 & R3 there is a directly connected `200.200.20.0/24` route configured on an interface, so that route has AD 0, which is the best AD value; higher is worse.

Use `show route` or `show ip route` to see the directly connected route for these routes where you see rib-failure.

BGP AD is configurable but defaults to 20 (eBGP, like your example network) or 200 (iBGP, within same AS or confederation.)  Here is [Cisco's table](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/border-gateway-protocol-bgp/15986-admin-distance.html#topic2) showing the default values for AD per routing protocol.  Common ones for simple network:

```
Protocol       Admin Distance default
Connected      0
Static         1
eBGP           20
OSPF           110
IS-IS          115
RIP            120
iBGP           200
```

There's not anything wrong with your configuration.  You've just misunderstood that you don't have to learn `200.200.20.0/24` on R1 or R3 since those routers are already directly-connected to that subnet.  That is what rib-failure is indicating.